# Backbonejs - in collection, how do we access this.var from initialize function?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

What I am trying to accomplish is pass this Post model ID to a collection so I can populate this specific Post id with other models that are associated with it. For example: In a Blog Post, contains a bunch of Comments. and I want to display those comments pointing to this Blog Post only.

I must be missing something fundamental here.

Below is my Post Model and i am instantiating a new CommentCollection and passing along models and options arguments.

```
var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    /*
     * we are connecting Comments collection
     * to each post item by passing along post id
     * */
    this.comments = new CommentsCollection([], { id: this.id });
  },
  defaults: {
    title: 'title here',
    body: 'body here'
  },
  urlRoot: localserver + "/posts"
});
```

Below is my Comment Collection. `console.log(this.id);` returns undefined.

```
var CommentsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function(models, options) {
    this.id = options.id;
    console.log(this.id);
    return this;
  },
  url: function() {
    console.log(this.id);
    return localserver + "/posts/" + this.id + "/comments";
  },
  model: CommentModel
});
```

my console is returning this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
3
```

Comment: You don't pass any id in `this.comments = new CommentsCollection([], { post:this });`

Comment: thanks @Xartok for pointing that out. I've updated my code above and it still doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var CommentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var CommentsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: CommentModel,
  initialize: function(models, options) {
    this.id = options.id;
    if(typeof this.id === 'undefined') { return; }
    this.url();
  },
  url: function() {
    var localserver = "localhost";
    console.log('from comment url: ', this.id);

    return localserver + "/" + this.id + "/comments";                  
  }
});


var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com" + "/posts",
  initialize: function(option) {
    this.comments = new CommentsCollection([], { id: option.id });
  }
});

//var pm = new PostModel();
//pm.comments.fetch();
//console.log('from pm: ', pm.comments.url());

var PostsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: PostModel, 
  url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com" + "/posts?_sort=views&_order=DESC",
  initialize: function() {
    this.on('reset', this.getComments, this);
  },
  getComments: function() {
    this.each(function(post) {
      post.comments = new CommentsCollection([], { post: post });
      post.comments.fetch();
    });
  }
});

var pc = new PostsCollection();
pc.fetch();
```

What I did is that I use the option parameter of the PostModal. Below is the code.

```
var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com" + "/posts",
  initialize: function(option) {
    this.comments = new CommentsCollection([], { id: option.id });
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the respond. i changed it with the code above and i still was not able to pass `this.id` to the url function. it also returns this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` i am currently updating my code above with the changes

Comment: i am not initiaizing the PostModel. I am initializing CommentsCollection inside of PostModel initialize function

Comment: ok so this has been a more detailed code ive been working on http://jsbin.com/godojipoxi/edit?js,console

Comment: What actually happen is that when you do call the fetch method of backbone collection, it automatically perform an instantiation of the PostModel that has an optional parameter. This parameter is the obj that is to be converted as an instance of PostModel.